# how do I pattern match a rapidjson object?

Tags: c++, regex, json, filestream

code:

```
int main()
{
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        FILE *fp = popen("/usr/bin/php getSome.php 155", "r");
        FileReadStream s(fp, buff, BUFSIZ);
        Document a;
        a.ParseStream(s);
        \\for (Value::ConstValueIterator itr = a.Begin(); itr != a.End(); ++itr)
            \\printf("%d ", itr->GetInt());
        printf(a[1]);

}
```

I have json data coming in that looks like this:

```
./phpMethod1.o
success:1
orderid:192877561
moreinfo:Your Buy order has been placed for<br><b>0.00100000 DRK @ 0.00517290 BTC</b> each.<br>Order ID: <b>192877561</b>
```

I am trying to get the key value for 'orderid'.

I have tried almost every method from here -> [rapidjson user guide](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/wiki/UserGuide) to access inbound json data and always get the same type of conversion error.

```
# g++ -g phpBuyMethod1.cpp -o phpBuyMethod1.o -std=gnu++11
phpBuyMethod1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
phpBuyMethod1.cpp:27:13: error: cannot convert 'rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int printf(const char*, ...)'
```

or if I attempt a for loop such as:

```
for (Value::ConstValueIterator itr = a.Begin(); itr != a.End(); ++itr)
    printf("%d ", itr->GetInt());
```

The code will compile but I get the following error at execution (basically choking on the same thing):

```
phpBuyMethod1.o: rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h:1167: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>* rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Begin() [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::ValueIterator = rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >*; rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator> = rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >]: Assertion `IsArray()' failed.
```

The moral is, I just can't get to the data for a pattern match.
How would I properly access the UTF-8 rapidjson object and do a pattern match for 'orderid'?

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided is not a valid JSON. A valid JSON is something like:

```
{
"success":1,
"orderid":192877561,
"moreinfo":"Your Buy order has been placed for<br><b>0.00100000 DRK @ 0.00517290 BTC</b> each.<br>Order ID: <b>192877561</b>"
}
```

The parsing should have failed. You can check whether the parsing is success by `a.HasParseError()`.

Besides, after parsing the above valid JSON, the root of it is an object type, you can use `a["moreinfo"]` to access its associated value.